# How do I render an entity view mode like 'teaser' in a twig template?

Tags: theming, 8, entities

I have an entity reference field in one content referencing an other content.

What I'm trying to achieve is to display that reference in a teaser format programmatically.

I was hoping that I could do something like this :

```
{{ node.field_entity_ref.view('teaser') }}
```

But that doesn't work. Do I need to declare a preprocess anyway ? If so what's the best practice ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best practice would be to configure the reference field in UI as teaser and use it in the node template:

```
{{ content.field_entity_ref }}
```

If this is not an option for your case, you would probably need some code in preprocess.

But much easier is to use the module [Twig Tweak](https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_tweak), which can render nodes without preprocess:

```
{{ drupal_entity('node', node.field_entity_ref.0.target_id, 'teaser') }}
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about Twig Tweak, that sounds like a winner ! Only thing that bother me is that key 0. Do you know how I can iterate on node.field_entity_ref ?

Comment: @pbonnefoi something along the lines of 
`{% set items = content.FIELD_NAME["#items"].getValue() %}
{% for item in items %}
  {{ drupal_entity('paragraph', item.target_id, 'VIEW_MODE') }}
{% endfor %}`